# symfony console make:auth keeps creating a custom authenticator

Tags: php, authentication, symfony

i created a Symfony 6 Application, but Forms Authentication keeps returning "Invalid Credentials".

First i tried to follow the Documentation to implement a simple Form Login.
But i always get "Invalid Credentials" when i try to authenticate that user.

Then i tried the make:auth command so it might create stuff im probably missing but even if i select Option one for a Login Form Authenticator it keeps creating a Custom Authenticator.
But i dont need anything Custom, just simple Forms Authentication.

So how do i use the Basic Forms Authenticator or create it with the console?

Answer (score 0):

Ok i finally found the issue.

The Form Authenticator works but the make:user command dont change what the documentation tells it should change.

In the security.yaml that part was missing

```yaml
    providers:
        app_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: email
```

Also under firewalls there wasnt a configuration to load the user:

```yaml
        firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    main:
        lazy: true
        provider: app_user_provider
```

now the authentication works like a charm.